# How to improve the resolution of exported ggsurvplot images in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I've used ggsurvplot to draw K-M curves based on my survival data.

When I export these using Rstudio's built in export function, I get very poor resolution and pixelated images that aren't clear enough for a publication.

I've tried different file formats (tiff, png, jpeg) but no difference.

How do I increase the resolution of these exported figures?

Comment: Check out `ggsave()` function: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html. This is a convenience function that internally calls functions such as `png()` or `jpeg()`, each of which has arguments allowing you to set the resolution of the exported image. Check the help documentation for those functions as well: `?png`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!